# Ionic Resources Android not working, Ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework

I running the command "ionic resources android" but it doing nothing. i have already placed new icon and splash png files with correct pixles but nothing happening for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QYQ7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing `cordova-res` as dev dependencies then run this command `ionic cordova resources --cordova-res` when running platform add. Run the command this way `ionic cordova platform add android --no-resources`